# Find minimum distance between a point and a curve in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, distance, numeric

I would like to use a MATLAB function to find the minimum length between a point and a curve? The curve is described by a complicated function that is not quite smooth. So I hope to use an existing tool of matlab to compute this. Do you happen to know one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone says "its complicated" the answer is always complicated too, since I never know exactly what you have. So I'll describe some basic ideas.

If the curve is a known nonlinear function, then use the symbolic toolbox to start with. For example, consider the function y=x^3-3*x+5, and the point (x0,y0) =(4,3) in the x,y plane.

Write down the square of the distance. Euclidean distance is easy to write.

```
(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 = (x - 4)^2 + (x^3 - 3*x + 5 - 3)^2
```

So, in MATLAB, I'll do this partly with the symbolic toolbox. The minimal distance must lie at a root of the first derivative.

```
sym x
distpoly = (x - 4)^2 + (x^3 - 3*x + 5 - 3)^2;
r = roots(diff(distpoly))
r =
      -1.9126              
      -1.2035              
       1.4629              
      0.82664 +    0.55369i
      0.82664 -    0.55369i
```

I'm not interested in the complex roots.

```
r(imag(r) ~= 0) = []
r =
      -1.9126
      -1.2035
       1.4629
```

Which one is a minimzer of the distance squared?

```
subs(P,r(1))
ans =
    35.5086

subs(P,r(2))
ans =
    42.0327

subs(P,r(3))
ans =
    6.9875
```

That is the square of the distance, here minimized by the last root in the list. Given that minimal location for x, of course we can find y by substitution into the expression for y(x)=x^3-3*x+5.

```
subs('x^3-3*x+5',r(3))
ans =
       3.7419
```

So it is fairly easy if the curve can be written in a simple functional form as above. For a curve that is known only from a set of points in the plane, you can use my [distance2curve](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34869-distance2curve) utility. It can find the point on a space curve spline interpolant in n-dimensions that is closest to a given point.

For other curves, say an ellipse, the solution is perhaps most easily solved by converting to polar coordinates, where the ellipse is easily written in parametric form as a function of polar angle. Once that is done, write the distance as I did before, and then solve for a root of the derivative.

A difficult case to solve is where the function is described as not quite smooth. Is this noise or is it a non-differentiable curve? For example, a cubic spline is "not quite smooth"  at some level. A piecewise linear function is even less smooth at the breaks. If you actually just have a set of data points that have a bit of noise in them, you must decide whether to smooth out the noise or not. Do you wish to essentially find the closest point on a smoothed approximation, or are you looking for the closest point on an interpolated curve?

For a list of data points, if your goal is to not do any smoothing, then a good choice is again my [distance2curve](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34869-distance2curve) utility, using linear interpolation. If you wanted to do the computation yourself, if you have enough data points then you could find a good approximation by simply choosing the closest data point itself, but that may be a poor approximation if your data is not very closely spaced.

If your problem does not lie in one of these classes, you can still often solve it using a variety of methods, but I'd need to know more specifics about the problem to be of more help.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways you could go about this.

The easy way that will work if your curve is reasonably smooth and you don't need too high precision is to evaluate your curve at a dense number of points and simply find the minimum distance:

```
t = (0:0.1:100)';
minDistance = sqrt( min( sum( bxsfun(@minus, [x(t),y(t)], yourPoint).^2,2)));
```

The harder way is to minimize a function of `t` (or `x`) that describes the distance

```
distance = @(t)sum( (yourPoint - [x(t),y(t)]).^2 );
%# you can use the minimum distance from above as a decent starting guess
tAtMin = fminsearch(distance,minDistance);

minDistanceFitte = distance(tAtMin);
```